# Gradle 14.4 Fails to Build - Gradle DSL method not found 'packageName()'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using productFlavors and attempting to change the packageName depending on the flavor:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        packageName "com.mypackagename.one"
    }
    flavor2 {
        packageName "com.mypackagename.two"
    }
}
```

This was working fine until I updated to Gradle 0.14.4, now it fails with the following message:

```
Error:(21, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'packageName()'

Possible causes:

The project 'MyProject' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a>

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>
```

1. How can I resolve this issue, whilst retaining the ability to change the packageNames for my flavors?
2. If this is simply because the method name has changed, where do I go to find out about these changes? I can't seem to find the associated changelog, or an updated doc explaining how to do this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> How can I resolve this issue, whilst retaining the ability to change the packageNames for my flavors?

Change them to `applicationId`:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.mypackagename.one"
    }
    flavor2 {
        applicationId "com.mypackagename.two"
    }
}
```

> where do I go to find out about these changes?

At the moment, go to [the documentation on the tools site](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).

Comment: Thank you. I was browsing the tools site, but I didn't realise changelogs for gradle were under 'new build system'. Good to know for future reference.