# Why can't I use packageName in productFlavors?

Tags: android, android-studio

The following code is from [Create Free/Paid versions of Application from same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590203/create-free-paid-versions-of-application-from-same-code/17286142#17286142)

But I get the error `Error:(18, 0) No such property: packageName for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.GroupableProductFlavor_Decorated`, why? Thanks!

```
productFlavors {
    lite {
        packageName = 'com.project.test.app'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
    }
    pro {
        packageName = 'com.project.testpro.app'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **ApplicationId** for defining different versions of your app. Read this

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

for a better understanding.

Comment: +1 
Based on a [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117214/gradle-14-4-fails-to-build-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-packagename), *should* is now *must*. `packageName` seems to have been removed.